# regular expression google analytics step

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to set up a funnel with a step that will include any page with /products/ within this url.  for example, it should include

sprout-kids.com/products/modern-kids-table-and-chair-set 
sprout-kids.com/collections/kids-playroom-furniture/products/modern-kids-table-and-chair-set

(notice that /products/ can occur in the middle as well)

But not include

sprout-kids.com/collections/kids-playroom-furniture

I am using regex as the destination type.  I have tried

.*/products/.*

as the funnel step Screen/Page but it work.  I have tried it in regex checkers like http://regexpal.com/ and it works their but not in analytics.  How do i get the funnel to include any path with something in the middle of it?

Answer (score 1):

You're really close.

Try this: `.*/products/.*`

`.*` - everything prior to the folder you want

`/products/` - the folder you want

`.*` - capture everything after the folder you want

It won't pickup `/collections/kids-playroom-furniture` because it doesn't contain `/products/`.